# How to apply custom score to a search filed in Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am making a search query in Elastic Search and I want to treat the fields the same when they match. For example if I search for field **field1** and it matches, then the _score is increase by 10(for example), same for the **field2**.

I was tried function_score but it's not working. It throws an error.

```
"caused_by": {
    "type": "class_cast_exception",
    "reason": "class 
               org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedSetDVOrdinalsIndexFieldData 
               cannot be cast to class 
               org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData 
               (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedSetDVOrdinalsIndexFieldData 
               and org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData are in unnamed 
               module of loader 'app')"
}
```

The query:

```
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "field1": {
                  "value": "Value 1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "field2": {
                  "value": "value 2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "field1",
            "factor": 10,
            "missing": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "field2",
            "factor": 10,
            "missing": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function score [with filter function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#:%7E:text=Furthermore%2C%20several%20functions%20can%20be%20combined.%20In%20this%20case%20one%20can%20optionally%20choose%20to%20apply%20the%20function%20only%20if%20a%20document%20matches%20a%20given%20filtering%20query) to boost.

assuming that your mapping looks like the one below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field_1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "field_2": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with documents

```
{"index":{}}
{"field_1": "foo", "field_2": "bar"}
{"index":{}}
{"field_1": "foo", "field_2": "foo"}
{"index":{}}
{"field_1": "bar", "field_2": "bar"}
```

you can use `weight` parameter to boost the documents matched for each query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "field_1": "foo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "field_2": "foo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 20
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As much as I read, the weight multiply the score of a certain match, so even if the weights are equal, the score could still be different and what I want is to set the scores equal. I am wrong?

Comment: that happens if you use the boost parameter[1] in the must query.
The key point of the query that I posted is unlike the must query calculates the score for each query, the filter query returns the constant score(1.0) whatever the query inside it is. [2] So the query will return the same score if the weight is the same.

*1: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html
*2: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below solution if you want to provide manual weight for different field in query. This will always replace highest weight field on top of your query response -

[Elasticsearch query different fields with different weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969740/elasticsearch-query-different-fields-with-different-weight/73971987#73971987)